# What Ubuntu 14.04 version do I use on my Compaq?

Tags: versions

wanting to install Ubuntu on a Compaq Presario sr2020nx what version do I use,  it has a AMD Athlon processor, with a Nvidia Geoforce 6150le video card on mb.

Comment: going to download from here http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Answer (score 0):

I used to run Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity) on my Compaq V3000, with 2G memory, Nvidia 6150 , and AMD T52 just fine.  Some people seem to have trouble getting Unity to run on the 6150, so unless you love Unity, lbuntu or xbuntu might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try Elementaryos(elementary.io). Its a good lightweight distro. 
I love their splash screen.